# Topological isomorphism, inverse function

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, inverse-function

> $c:=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}\colon \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)~ \text{exists}\}$ and $c_0:=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}\colon \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0\}$ both with $||f(n)||_\infty=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f(n)|$. Let $T: c_0\to c$  with $(Tf)(n):=f(n+1)+f(1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Show, that $T$ is a topological isomorphism.

To show that $T$ is a topological isomorphism first of all $T$ has to be linear.
Then $T$ must be bijective and $T$ as well as $T^{-1}$ have to be continuous.

That $T$ is linear is clear. For $f,g\in c$ and $\mu, \lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ it is:

$(T(\lambda f+\mu g))(n)=(\lambda f+\mu g)(n+1)+(\lambda f+\mu g)(1)\\=(\lambda f)(n+1)+(\lambda f)(1)+(\mu g)(n+1)+(\mu g)(1)\\=(T(\lambda f))(n)+(T(\mu g))(1)$

Now I want to find $T^{-1}$.
Do I have to find $T^{-1}$ such that:

$T^{-1}((Tf)(n))\stackrel{?}{=}f(n)$ and $T((T^{-1}f)(n))\stackrel{?}{=}f(n)$

But I do not succeed...
Can you give a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Fix $f\in c_0$.  Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}Tf(n)=f(1)+\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n+1)=f(1)$$
Now suppose $g\in c$.  What should $T^{-1}g(1)$ be?

Comment: I have to choose $T^{-1}g(1)$ such that $T(T^{-1}g(1))=g(1)$. So I tried $T^{-1}g(1)=g(0)$. Then we get $T(T^{-1}g(1))=T(g(0))=g(1+0)+g(1)$, which might be the right direction?

Comment: I think in this problem we consider $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ (this is almost universal in analysis).

Comment: I tried to figure out what $T^{-1}g(1)$ should be, but I do not get it...

Comment: $(T^{-1}g)(1)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)$.  Now calculate $(T^{-1}g)(n)$ for all other $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $T$ can be seen as 
$$
T(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(a_2+a_1,a_3+a_1,a_4+a_1,\ldots)
$$
To "come back", you need to put the limit of the sequence in the first coordinate, and subtract it from the other entries: if we write $b_\infty$ for the limit of the sequence $(b_n)$, 
$$
T^{-1}(b_1,b_2,\ldots)=(b_\infty, b_1-b_\infty,b_2-b_\infty,\ldots)
$$

Comment: I do not quite understand why we can view $T$ like this. Why do we get a sequence?

Comment: A function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C$ and a sequence are exactly the same object. I would say that it is the only way to define a sequence.

Comment: That makes it more clear for me, I guess. I never viewed it as a sequence in the first place, but now that you say it, it makes sense.

Comment: If you think about it, writing $a_n$ or $a(n)$ is just a matter of notation.

Comment: But how can I define $T^{-1}$? Is it $T^{-1}g(n)=g(n)-\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$

Comment: $$T^{-1}f(n)=\begin{cases}\lim_mf(m),&\ n=1\\ \ \\ f(n-1)-\lim_mf(m),&\ n\geq2\end{cases}$$

Comment: But how do I calculate $T(T^{-1}f(n))$ with this definition? Suppose n=1, then $T(T^{-1}f(1))=T(\lim_{m\to\infty} f(m))=\lim_{m\to\infty} f(m+1)+f(1)=f(1)$. For $n\geq 2$: $T(T^{-1}f(n))=T(f(n-1)-\lim_{m}f(m))=f(n)+f(1)-(\lim_m f(m)+f(1))=f(n)$. Using that $T$ is linear.

Comment: $T$ and $T^{-1}$ do not evaluate on numbers; they evaluate on functions.

Comment: What have I done wrong?

Comment: You write, for instance, $T(\lim_m f(m))$. That's meaningless; $T$ maps functions to functions, $T$ evaluated at a number makes no sense.

Comment: But how do I proof that the functions are inverse else? I just tried to use the definition of $T^{-1}f(n)$

Comment: If you write $g=T^{-1}f$, then $$Tg(n)=g(n+1)+g(1)=f(n)-\lim_mf(m)+\lim_mf(m)=f(n).$$